# tvOS - Focus particular item in a Table View

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, tvos

In **tvOS** development - By the default the focus of the table view is the 1st item. But, how to focus particular item by default in a Table View.

For Example, By default, I want to focus the **n**th row of the table view.

Thanks for your help in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To control the focus engine in general you have to override the methods provided by `UIFocusEnvironment` and/or the related `UITableViewDelegate` and `UICollectionViewDelegate` methods.  This behaves much differently than controlling something like the selected row/item, in that it's a global system and not specific to a particular view.

In your particular case, it may be sufficient to implement the `indexPathForPreferredFocusedViewInTableView(_:)` method that is available on `UITableViewDelegate` (note that there is an equivalent method for `UICollectionViewDelegate`).

One problem I ran into while attempting to do something similar was how the default chain of preferred focus views works.  Eventually I noticed this part of [the documentation for `UIFocusEnvironment`](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFocusEnvironment_Protocol/index.html) (which all views and view controllers conform to):

> By default, UIView returns itself and UIViewController returns its
>   root view. Returning self in a focusable view indicates that view
>   should be focused. Returning self in an unfocusable view causes the
>   focus engine to pick a default preferred focused view, by finding the
>   closest focusable subview to the top-leading corner of the screen.
>   Returning nil indicates that there is no preferred focused view.

In my case this meant that the focus engine was picking a default preferred focus view and the focus related delegate methods for my `UICollectionView` were not being called as I expected.  If you find this is the case you may need to implement `preferredFocusedView` (defined in the `UIFocusEnvironment` protocol) on your view controller subclass and return your instance of `UITableView` so that the delegate methods related to focus get invoked reliably.

Answer (score 0):

With TVML, it's the attribute `autoHighlight="true"`
(https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/TVJSAttributes.html)

Doesn't work with all templates, though, there still seem to be some bugs in the system.

Comment: I feel like Imad is using native instead of TVML, so I'm not sure that your answer is relevant.

Comment: Yes, I'm using native not TVML.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first,

1. During the view Load, set:

```
override var preferredFocusEnvironments: [UIFocusEnvironment] {
        return [myTableView]
    }
```

2. To focus to a particular IndexPath,

```
func indexPathForPreferredFocusedView(in tableView: UITableView) -> IndexPath? {
        if focusAtIndexPathRow != -1 {
            return IndexPath(item: focusAtIndexPathRow, section: 0)
        } else {
            return IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
        }
    }
```